# Trouble identifying the right query involving my two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm programming a website that serves as a bridge between people looking for blood donations for their loved ones, and willing blood donors.

In order for a registered blood donor to set a blood donation appointment, they should first open a "Blood requests page" where they can find patients to whom they can donate to.

I want the page to show blood donation requests that:

1. The donor has not set an appointment to donate to
2. don't have any blood donation appointments set for them yet.

This is my first table: blooddonationrequests. All requests for blood donations made by users on the site will go here (AcquirerID refers to the User ID of a user who has made the request for blood donation for the patient)

```
| Name            | Type           | Collation          | Null | Default |
| ----------------| -------------- |--------------------|------|---------|
| patientID (FK)  | int(11)        |                    |      |         |
| acquirerID (FK) | int(11)        |                    |      |         |
| requestID (PK)  | varchar(255)   | utf8mb4_general_ci |  No  |    None |
| datePosted      | date           |                    |  No  |    None |  
| approved        |tinyint(1)      |                    |  No  |   0     |
| archived        |tinyint(1)      |                    |  No  |   0     |
```

Here's my second table, tblappointments. This is where all appointments made by registered donors of the site will go to

```
| Name                | Type       |Collation          |Null    |Default|   Extra|
|---------------------|------------|-------------------|--------|-------|--------|
| id (PK)             |int(11)     |                   | No     | None  |AUTO_INCREMENT
| healthCenterID (FK) |int(11)     |                   | No     | None  |
|donorID (FK)         |int(11)     |                   | No     | None  |
|patientID (FK)       |int(11)     |                   | No     | None  |
|donationRequestID(FK)|varchar(255)|utf8mb4_general_ci | No     | None  |
|apptDate             |date        |                   | No     | None  |
|timeSlotID (FK)      |int(11)     |                   | No     | None  |
|confirmed            |tinyint(1)  |                   | No     |  0    | 
|completed            |tinyint(1)  |                   | No     | 0     |
```

This is the first query I tried

```
SELECT request.patientID FROM blooddonationrequest as request 
LEFT JOIN tblappointment as appt ON appt.donationRequestID = request.requestID 
WHERE appt.donationRequestID IS NULL
```

It successfully returns all blood donation requests that don't have scheduled appointments, but how about the blood donation requests that already have scheduled appointments by other donors, but not the donor that is currently logged in? This is what I struggle with

I made a lot of trial and error with the SQL code, which I failed to record and save, but mostly they're just modifications of the SQL above. I tried desperately including stuff to the query like `and appt.donorID != $_SESSION['userID']`, but of course that didn't work.

So, what queries should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Your model and your request were not very clear to me - I had to read it 5 times to try to understand what you had and what you are asking for.  Let me try to play it back for you to see if I understand it.

You have a list of patients (PatientID) who are either asking for a blood donation or have had someone else (AcquirerID) ask on their behalf.  You have a second list of Donor appointments who have been matched to a request in the first table.  For some reason you are storing both a link to the request AND a link to the patient in the same table which is not very normalized and may have led to some data anomalies.

You would like to find all the patients who have an outstanding request but no appointment yet.

When stated that way I would join the two tables not on the RequestID but on the PatientID and look for NULLs.

```
Select R.PatientID From blooddonationrequests R Left Outer Join tblappointments A
                          On R.PatientID=A.PatientID
Where A.PatientID Is Null
```

Since your model allow the same patient to request donations several times, you may need to group them together if you only want a single patient once.

Comment: Thank you, This query effectively doesn't show blood donation requests that already have an appointment. I want the page to display blood donation requests that the *current Logged In Donor* hasn't made an appointment for yet. Meaning, a blood donation request may already have an appointment set by Donor A, but if Donor B logs in, and hasn't set an appointment for that request yet, said request should still be visible on the page.